# Customizing Google's MailApp.sendEmail Function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a 2 part question: First I would like to replace the hardcoded email address with the variable (manager) acquired from the form. I have not been able to get it to work successfully and I believe I am using the wrong formatting.

```js
function sendEmail(e) {
  var email = e.values[1];
  var sub = e.values[2];
  var manager = e.values[3]; 
  var date = e.values[4];
  var checkin = e.values[5];
  var checkout = e.values[6];
  var totalminutes = e.values[7];
  var purpose = e.values[8];
  
  MailApp.sendEmail("<someone@google.com>", "Internal Sub Payment Request", 
                    "What no html?", {htmlBody: html});  
}
```

The second part is how do I CC someone on this email? When I tried adding it I get the message "Cannot find method sendEmail(string,string,string,string,object). (line 24, file "Code")"

```js
MailApp.sendEmail(e.parameter.reply, "Internal Sub Payment Request Status", 
                    "Your manager said: "+ answer);
```

Comment: The reason it gives you an error as you are not writing cc in a correct format as defined for MailApp.sendEmail() function in google apps script. I recommend you check this [help article](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(Object)).

Answer (score 0):

If you're sending to multiple email addresses, you need to make sure that they are comma separated in a String. It looks like you've got too many arguments from the error `(string,string,string,string,object)`

**A simple send**

```
MailApp.sendEmail("email1@gmail.com, email2@gmail.com", "Subject", "Body");
```

**To add CC addresses**, add in a `cc` property to the fourth optional object parameter.

```
MailApp.sendEmail('email1@gmail.com, email2@gmail.com', "Subject", "Body", 
    { cc: "ccaddress@gmail.com, ccaddress2@gmail.com" });
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app

Comment: Thanks this helps, I think my issue with it was the placement of the (")'s as I had each address in separate quotes which it read at separate strings.  trying this now.  Any idea on the first part of my question?

Comment: If `manager` is a String, then you can just use the variable as the recipient. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: MailApp.sendEmail("<someone@google.com>, "+ manager+" ", "Internal Sub Payment Request", 
                    "What no html?", {htmlBody: html});

Comment: `MailApp.sendEmail(manager, "Internal Sub Payment Request", "What no html?", {htmlBody: html});`